# python - how to concatenate two index from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
listvalue = ['charity','hospital','carrefour']
```

I tried to concat two index from a list:

```
twoconcat = [listvalue[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(listvalue))]
```

The output I am getting is:

```
[['charity', 'hospital'], ['hospital', 'carrefour'], ['carrefour']]`
```

I want the output to be

```
[['charity','hospital'],['charity','carrefour'],['hospital','charity'],['hospital','carrefour'],['carrefour','charity'],['carrefour','hospital']]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about list comprehension. This can be helpful,
runs on python 2.x

```
listvalue = ['charity','hospital','carrefour']

arr_len= len(listvalue)

result=[]
for i in range(arr_len):
    for j in range(arr_len):
        if i !=j:
            result.append([listvalue[i],listvalue[j]])
print result
```

## result

```
[['charity', 'hospital'], ['charity', 'carrefour'], ['hospital', 'charity'], ['hospital', 'carrefour'], ['carrefour', 'charity'], ['carrefour', 'hospital']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
>>> places = ['charity','hospital','carrefour']
>>> list(itertools.permutations(places, 2))
[('charity', 'hospital'), ('charity', 'carrefour'), ('hospital', 'charity'), 
('hospital', 'carrefour'), ('carrefour', 'charity'), ('carrefour', 'hospital')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[[x, y] for x in l for y in l if y != x]
```

Output :

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'a'], ['c', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alasdair is right...use itertools.

Code:

```
 from itertools import permutations

 places = ['charity','hospital','carrefour']
 result = list(permutations(places, 2)
```

Output:

```
[('charity', 'hospital'), ('charity', 'carrefour'), ('hospital', 'charity'), ('hospital', 'carrefour'), ('carrefour', 'charity'), ('carrefour', 'hospital')]
```

Code:

```
from itertools import permutations
places = ['charity','hospital','carrefour']
result = [list(place) for place in list(permutations(places, 2))]
```

Output:

```
[['charity','hospital'],['charity','carrefour'],['hospital','charity'],['hospital','carrefour'],['carrefour','charity'],['carrefour','hospital']]
```